# Problems with the assignment of classes to each other

Tags: c++

I can't figure out what is causing the error when I try to convert the classes.
**The object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "Gradien::setAngel".**

> Overload operator that converts a degree into a gradient

```cpp
Gradien& operator=(const Degree& d) const { 
    int a = static_cast<int>((d.getAngel() / 360.0) * 400);
    setAngel(a);
    return *this;
}
```

In this case Gradien is a subclass from Degree, they look almost identical:

```cpp
class Gradien : public Degree
{
private:
    int angle = 400;

    const string unit = " gon";

public:
    Gradien() = default;
    Gradien(int a) : Degree(a) {};
    int getAngel() const { return angle; } 
    void setAngel(int w) { angle = w; }
    string getUnit() const { return unit; }
}
```

i tried to change sth by removing the consts but no change. this seems to cause the problem:
`setAngel(a);`

happy for help :)

Comment: Picking at nits:  @MsSunshine: what's the difference between an Angle and an Angel?  You may want to throw in some saints and devil variables too.

Comment: Why is Gradien inheriting from Degree in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

The assignment operator is `const` qualified:

```cpp
Gradien& operator=(const Degree& d) const { 
//                                  ^^^^^
```

which makes calling `setAngel` (that is *not* `const` qualified) invalid:

```cpp
    setAngel(a);
```

Having a `const` qualified assignment operator is probably defeating the purpose of having an assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

You declared your `operator=` overload as `const`. It is a const-method. You can call it on non-const or on const objects, but the method cannot modify the object.

It (almost) never makes sense to declare `operator=` as `const`. Assigning to something usually requires to modify that something.